# Difficulty with GridView PostBack Events

Tags: events, gridview, postback

In the RowDataBound OnClick event handler, its printing `'Hi'` when I click on any row. But I want it to only print 'Hi' when I click on the 15th row. How can I implement this?

My code:

```
protected void dtvExDetails_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.DataItemIndex == -1)
        return;

    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver","this.style.cursor='hand';");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.GetPostBackClientEvent(dtvExDetails, "Select$15"));
}


protected void dtvExDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("hi");
    DataGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  protected void dtvExDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            GridViewRow selrow = sender as GridViewRow;

            if(selrow.Count == 15)
                Response.Write("hi");
            DataGrid();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but better use this ...its working fine...

if (e.Row.DataItemIndex == 14)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.GetPostBackClientEvent(dtvExDetails, "Select$15"));
        }